# Debounce function unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I am using a [debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce) function inside componentDidMount like so:

```
    ...
    if (setNavigationSections) {
        setNavigationSections(filteredFieldGroups);
        window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(50, this.getNavigationActive));
    }  
    ...
```

and I have a unit test for it like so:

```
    it('should add a scroll handler on mount', () => {
        // const d = instance.getNavigationActive;
        // const deb = debounce(50, d);
        // expect(window.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith('scroll', deb); 
        expect(window.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith('scroll', instance.getNavigationActive);
    });
```

the unit test fails and the message is:
[image]

I have tried a possible solution like the one in the commented code but it still fails.

Do I need maybe to mock the debounce function in another way?

Answer (score 1):

In real code, the `addEventListener` method is called with `scroll` and `debounce`, but while testing we are trying to test with wrong second parameter.
You can mock the debounce method by using jest.mock, as below:

```
import { debounce } from 'throttle-debounce';
jest.mock('throttle-debounce', () => {
    return {
        debounce: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('mockDebouncedValue')
    }
})
describe('your test description', () => {
    it('should add a scroll handler on mount', () => {
        // here debounce points to the mocked function
        // since addEventListener is called with the value which is returned after calling debounce, so we check here.
        expect(window.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith('scroll','mockDebouncedValue');
        expect(debounce).toBeCalled();
    });
 });
```